# Appending output of command in for loop

Tags: shell-script, files

I am using a simple for loop to process certain input files and get the output in one file. What I am using is

```
for k in ../some_directory/*.txt; 
    do command (containing -i $k -o outputfile.txt); 
done
```

Now each loop gives an output. I want the output to be written in one file. This loop just replaces all the previous files and gives me a number of outputfile.txt files each with the output from every loop. How can I append the command to one file? I don't want the screen output but the output from each of the command.

NOTE: I am not talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612603/redirecting-output-of-bash-for-loop) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755244/output-for-loop-to-a-file)

Comment: You can try `&>>` or `>>` nstread of `-o` to get the output. the only difference on those link os `>` this will overwrite the file again and again if you use `>>` twice it will append the output.

Comment: another solution to redirect the output of `for...done` to a single file. The `command` should be capable to direct its output to `stdout` by default or by supplying a dash (`-`) to `-o` option (the widely used convention)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options here to get your desired result:

```
for k in /path/to/*.txt; do
    some_command -i "$k" >> /path/to/output.txt
done
```

**OR**

```
for k in /path/to/*.txt; do
    some_command -i "$k"
done >> /path/to/output.txt
```

If your program doesn't write to standard output, and *only* writes to a file specified with `-o`, you can do this:

```
for k in /path/to/*.txt; do
    some_command -i "$k" -o /tmp/output.txt
    cat /tmp/output.txt >> /path/to/real_output.txt
done
rm /tmp/output.txt
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work. Maybe my question is not clear enough. So I have a file. I give this as an input file to the command in the loop. If I don't specify any -o file, the output gets appended to this input file. Now I want to loop it so that in every loop the output gets appended to this same input file.

Comment: I have updated my proposed answer to reflect this.

Comment: The parens are not needed in the second `for` loop. Doing `for ...; do ... done >>outfile` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of a simpler solution. I just needed to give the same file name as output as the input. That solved my problem as all the changes get appended and the old output file gets backed up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for name in ../some_directory/*.txt; do
    outfile="$name"-out
    command (containing -i "$name" -o "$outfile"); 
done
```

This would construct the name of the output file from the name of the input file by simply appending the string `-out` to it.

Note that `outfile=out-"$name"` would not work as `$name` also contains the path to the filename.

Would you want to prepend a string to the filename, you cold do

```
outdir=${name%/*}        # remove filename component from $name
outfile=out-${name##*/}  # remove the path component from $name (and prepend string)
```

Then use `$outdir/$outfile` as the output file path.